# Euler-Arnold equation

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, lie-algebra

In https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.05765, I came across the Euler-Arnold equation which is equation (2.8) reproduced here for convenience:
\begin{equation}
G_{ab}\frac{dv^b}{ds}-f_{ca}\,^d\,G_{de}\,v^cv^e=0. \tag{2.8}
\end{equation}
My question is: Is the Euler-Arnold equation, just the geodesic equation written in frame basis?

I tried to recast the geodesic equation written in world indices in terms of frame basis and I obtain is the following:
\begin{equation}
\frac{dv^{a}}{ds}+\omega_{\mu \,b}\,^{a} e^{\mu}\,_{c}\, v^{b} v^{c}=0
\end{equation}
wherein, if I use the Maurer-Cartan equations:
\begin{equation}
\omega_{\mu b}\,^a=\frac{1}{2}f_{cb}\,^a\,e^c\,_{\mu}
\end{equation} 
to recast spin connection in terms of structure constants, I do not obtain any thing similar to the Euler-Arnold equation.

Since, the paper is supposed to first solve the geodesic equation and then proceed from there, but they seem to be solving the Euler-Arnold equation instead.

Therefore,  I finally want to know is that what is the relevance of Euler-Arnold equation in relation to the geodesic equation?

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/533227/2451