# Relation of the Geodesic equation on the Lie group manifold with the Euler-Arnold equation

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, group-theory, lie-algebra

I am trying to write the geodesic equation on the Lie group manifold and recast it in terms of frame basis to arrive at the geodesic equation on the Lie algebra. However, in  https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.05765, the authors claim the geodesic equation to be:
\begin{equation}
G_{a\,b}\frac{dv^b}{ds}-f_{a\,c}\,^d\,G_{d\,b}v^b\,v^c=0
\end{equation}
 called the Euler-Arnold equation. This equation looks different from the one that is obtained by simply writing the geodesic equation on the group manifold and later, transforming to the non coordinate or frame basis to obtain:
\begin{equation}
\frac{dv^a}{ds}+\omega_{\mu\,b}\,^a\,e^{\mu}\,_c\,v^b\,v^c
\end{equation}
 and further using the Maurer-Cartan equations:
\begin{equation}
\omega_{\mu\,b}\,^a=\frac{1}{2}f_{c\,b}\,^a\,e^c\,_{\mu}
\end{equation}
 to recast spin connection in terms of structure equations. The equation so obtained, is not the one mentioned above.

I want to know the relevance of using the Euler-Arnold equation instead of the one obtained simply by transforming to the frame variables.

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/534177/2451